# Error when installing web3 and ganache

Tags: node.js, npm, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

This is the error I get when running `npm install --save mocha ganache-cli web3@1.0.0-beta.26` :

```
rohitgoud$ npm install --save mocha ganache-cli web3@1.0.0-beta.26

> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall /Users/rohitgoud/node_modules/scrypt

> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js

Error: Error: Command failed: ./configure
configure: error: in `/Users/rohitgoud/node_modules/scrypt/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

> scrypt@6.0.3 install /Users/rohitgoud/node_modules/scrypt

> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "/anaconda3/bin/python" is v3.6.4, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failPythonVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:492:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:474:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:267:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:567:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/rohitgoud/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/rohitgoud/package.json'
npm WARN webpack-cli@2.0.15 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN rohitgoud No description
npm WARN rohitgoud No repository field.
npm WARN rohitgoud No README data
npm WARN rohitgoud No license field.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/rohitgoud/.npm/_logs/2018-04-26T01_45_43_548Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Comment: Rewriting the stacktrace in a code block and setting the title to something more user (and search) friendly

Answer (score 0):

you need install python2.7(recommend)